# Disable navigating up in embedded document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, iframe, embedded

I embedded a document library on my SharePoint site using a custom embed Web Part.

The embed code looks like this:

```
<iframe src="https://myorg.sharepoint.com/sites/mysite/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder=%2Fsites%mysite%2Fmyfolder" width="500" height="500"></iframe>
```

It works great.

However, I'd like to prevent users from exiting the `RootFolder`. They can currently do so by clicking the navigation bar at the top.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**No**, this is not possible.

While using `iframe` in embed web part there is no control on what to show and what not in web part.

You cannot restrict users from clicking on navigation bar.